# Find 3 words from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having problem how to use regex and it's been half day searching the commands, I hope anyone can help me with this issue.

the string:

```
ProductTable ChairStyleNewproductLocationUnited Kingdom
```

What I want is, get the words: `Table Chair`, `Newproduct` and the last is `United Kingdom`. FYI there are few spaces in the string.

Thank you

Comment: Could you mention the language you are using the regex in please?

Comment: More potential input and more information on it's format would be helpful.

Comment: I am using javascript..

Comment: So what's stopping you? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to post more input, because your data format is vague right now...

But I'll try to answer anyway:

```
^\s*Product(.+?)Style(.+?)Location(.+?)\s*$
```

Your info is in the 3 captured groups. I can't say more until I know the language you're using.

**EDIT:** In JS:

```
var re = /^\s*Product(.+?)Style(.+?)Location(.+?)\s*$/gm;
var inputString = "ProductTable ChairStyleNewproductLocationUnited Kingdom";
// Add another line of data
inputString += "\nProductDeskStyleOldproductLocationGermany";

var match;
while((match = re.exec(inputString))) {
    console.log({
        product: match[1],
        style: match[2],
        location: match[3]
    });
}
```

Comment: @user3670443 Ok, I've added a JS example

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> exp = r'^Product(?P<product>(.*?))Style(?P<style>(.*?))Location(?P<loc>(.*?))$'
>>> i = "ProductTable ChairStyleNewproductLocationUnited Kingdom"
>>> results = re.match(exp, i).groupdict()
>>> results['loc']
'United Kingdom'
>>> results['product']
'Table Chair'
>>> results['style']
'Newproduct'
```